# Windows 10 Using Visual Studio Express 2015 to build program using SQL Server CE just hangs on other platforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, express, sql-server-ce

I am using Visual Studio Express 2015 to build an application that reads a SQL Server CE database (I was reading a SQLite database but want to change, the sqlite program work fine). When I build on on machine it runs fine.

When I copy the binary and `.sdf` file to another machine (I have tried Vista and Windows 7, both 64 bit), the program hangs when starting. It never comes back. I can't even kill the process. I have to reboot.

I thought it must be something I am doing so I downloaded the source for CompactView and it does the same thing however if I install CompactView from the installer it runs fine.

Any ideas that would cause my program to hang and never return?

Also I am building for x86 and .net framework 4 client profile

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Avast was blocking the program from running.  Once I disabled Avast it ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

It could be permisions.windows vista & windows 7 have stricted permision policies.try in other folder